Chrome browser not showing Home and Settings

After the latest software update on my Google Pixel 9, I can no longer see the Home button or "..." menu (Settings) on the Google Chrome browser.
I did a lot of troubleshooting with the app, related apps, other settings, and finally factory reset the phone. The issue persists! I called Pixel support and confirmed that this is not intentional. I tried the URLs: chrome://settings, chrome://history, etc. but they didn't work. I am out tricks - and Google Support is useless.
How does one get to the home page or settings? Could this be malware? I did just experience a serious hack (related to bitcoin) on the phone. Any thoughts?

Based on the screenshot you provided, I think you are using the Google app instead of the Chrome app.
The Google app provides news and access to Google search results that open in your default browser. The Google app is not a browser. If you click a search result in the Google app, it will open in webview (which is just your default browser being used to display webpages in other apps).
The Chrome app is a browser (just like Chrome on your computer) with the default search engine of Chrome being Google, though you can change the default search engine.
The Chrome app can be uninstalled, while the Google app can't. If you accidentally uninstalled Chrome, you can install Chrome again, or install a different browser from the Play Store.
